# GZipStream как получить размер разархивированных данных?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gzip

Доброго времени суток.
Допустим я имею некие данные, которые как мне известно представляют собой заархивированные данные(результат работы GZipStream)

```
byte[] data=...;
```

Создаю экземпляр GZipStream с CompressionMode.Decompress

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
GZipStream decompressStream = new GZipStream(ms,CompressionMode.Decompress);
```

Как я понимаю, теперь разархивированные данные можно извлекать путем вызова

```
decompressStream.Read(byte[], int, int);
```

или

```
decompressStream.ReadByte()
```

У родительского класса Stream есть свойство Length, но в GZipStream оно не поддерживается(вызывает исключение NotSupportedException).
Вопрос: как получить длину разархивированных данных? Может быть это значение записано в самом файле? Скорее всего я не понимаю философию работы данного механизма, прошу направить меня в нужном направлении.
Заранее спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/638039/GZipStream-length-when-uncompressed